# Setting up nginx for socket-io and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, nginx

I have a project which did not require socket-io till now, with following nginx configuration

```
server {
    server_name app.web.com;
    root /var/www/app/releases/current/public/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 503 @maintenance;

    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
        return 503;
    }

    location @maintenance {
        error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html break;
    }

    location ~ ^/(js|css|images|media|system)/ {
        autoindex off;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        expires 4w;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:7485;
    }
}
```

Now I have added a chat feature in it using socket-io. How do I add enable socket from nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure socket.io to [serve on specific path](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#path(v:string):server) (eg `/socketio`).
When you should add following to your Nginx config:

```
location /socketio {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    break;
}
```

change `http://127.0.0.1:4000` to address listen by socket.io in your app.

Comment: so if my socket is trying to connect to ws://www.app.com/socket.io/

it should be "location /socket.io" {}